# Synchronizing the databases

Tags: database, synchronization

I am developing an web application in which i need to maintain the website in the local servers itself with the database in the computer itself , the local database will change periodically.There is a central database through which i have to access all the data in all the remaining DB's .

The problem is that even when internet connection is disabled, the local server will update the local database but when when it regains the internet connection it has to update the central database with the local modified data.

The tables( i mean the database schema, table names, attributes all)  in all the DB's is same.The data should be appended if added any new ,should be deleted if any deleted and  should be modified if any.

I am using MySQL server as DB, Apache Tomcat as server and using JSP, Servlets for business logic.

Comment: Vague title is unlikely to be useful to future visitors to the site.

Answer (score 0):

Please visit http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-howto.html

Mysql replication might do the job but there are a few things that you have to consider, like:

- the amount of data that has to be synchronized
- the OS used on master and slave servers
- because of the internet connection issue - why you disable internet connection? one option might be a scheduled job (crontab)

Comment: thank you very much for answering my question. I'll check that immediately, All the OS's using are Windows-7 only.

Comment: But I have to send the data from slaves (many) to Master and it shouldn't overwrite the database rather it should append it there.